# awk bash repeat pattern

Tags: awk, sed, git-bash

I currently have this ORIGINAL string:

```
mklink .\Oracle\MOLT_HYB_01\110_Header\pkg_cdc_util.pks $.\Oracle\MOLT_HYB_01\110_Header\pkg_cdc_util.pks
#.......................................................^
```

....and need to replace as follows:

```
mklink .\Oracle\MOLT_HYB_01\110_Header\pkg_cdc_util.pks ..\..\..\..\.\Oracle\MOLT_HYB_01\110_Header\pkg_cdc_util.pks
#.......^......^...........^..........^.................^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

i.e. replace **$** with "..\" 4 times based on the number of slashes in the 2nd column of the ORIGINAL string (".\Oracle\MOLT_HYB_01\110_Header\pkg_cdc_util.pks")

I can for example do the following individually:

1. `awk -F '\\' '{print NF-1}'` --> to print the number of occurrences of the backward slash
2. `sed -e "s,\\\,$(printf '..\\\%.0s' {1..4}),g"` --> to replace and repeat the string pattern

......but unsure how to string together in 1 command line.

Comment: [edit] your question and use the editor `{}` button to fix the formatting of your code and sample input/output. Also clarify if your input string is in a file or in a shell variable or in a pipe or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `awk` command that works with an arbitrary number of input lines (with the same field structure):

```
awk -v prefixUnit="..\\" '{
  count = gsub("\\\\", "\\", $2) # count the number of "\"s
  # Build the prefix composed of count prefixUnit instances
  prefix = ""; for (i=1; i<=count; ++i) prefix = prefix prefixUnit 
  $3 = prefix substr($3, 2) # prepend the prefix to the 3rd field, replacing the "$"
  print # print result
 }' file
```

As a condensed one-liner:

```
awk -v pu="..\\" '{n=gsub("\\\\","\\",$2);p="";for(i=1;i<=n;++i)p=p pu;$3=p substr($3,2);print}' file
```

Comment: All useful answers but because I have multiple lines, this worked. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use perl, although this is a bit "clever"

```
perl -ane '
    $n = ($F[1] =~ tr/\\/\\/);
    $F[2] =~ s{\$}{"..\\" x $n}e;
    print join(" ", @F);
' file
```

where

- `-a` - autosplit the line into the array `@F`
- `-n` - execute the body for each line of "file"
- `$F[1] =~ tr/\\/\\/` - count the number of backslashes in the 2nd field
- `$F[2] =~ s{\$}{"..\\" x $n}e` - replace the dollar with the right number of "..\"

Answer (score 0):

awk one-liner, assuming that there is just a single line to process

```
awk -F\\ -v RS='$' -v ORS='' '{print} NR==1{for(i=1; i< NF; i++) printf("..\\")}'
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -F\\ -v RS='$' ' -v ORS='' ' # Specify separators

    {print}                      # print the line

    NR==1{                       # for first record
      for (i=1; i<NF; i++)       # print multiple ..\
         printf("..\\")          # need to escape \\
    }
'
```